# Is there any way that the two 'different' programs of arduino can be run one after another keeping each one separate?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

I have made a 8*8*8 led cube using arduino. I have found two different codes from different developers having different animations in them. i wanted to combine them and get to run all the animations at once. Both the codes have some similar function names and some are different as well. I wanted to know if i can keep both these separate from each other yet run them one after another. Almost all parameters are different including setup() of both codes. Please help

Comment: Define "after". An Arduino program runs constantly until you tell it otherwise (by removing the power, pressing reset, uploading a new program, etc). There is no "after" to an Arduino program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this fairly simply by using **namespaces**. Inside a namespace, symbols are relative to that space. So you could put all of your first sketch into the namespace sketch1, and all of the second sketch into the namespace sketch2 (assuming it all fits, of course).

Now you can call the first sketch's setup and then loop, by qualifying it with the namespace name as illustrated below.

```
// FIRST SKETCH

namespace sketch1
{

  // FUNCTION PROTOTYPES

  void func1(int a, int b);
  void func2();

  void setup()
  {
    Serial.begin (115200);
    Serial.println ("Inside sketch1 setup");
    func1 (5, 6);
  }

  void loop()
  {
    Serial.println ("Inside sketch1 loop");
    delay (1000);
    func2 ();
  }

  void func1(int a, int b)
  {
    // some function
  }

  void func2()
  {
    // some other function
  }

} // end of namespace sketch1

// SECOND SKETCH

namespace sketch2
{

  // DECLARE FUNCTIONS BEFORE CALLING THEM

  void func3(int a, int b)
  {
    // some function
  }

  void func4()
  {
    // some other function
  }

  void setup()
  {
    Serial.begin (115200);
    Serial.println ("Inside sketch2 setup");
    func3 (7, 8);
  }

  void loop()
  {
    Serial.println ("Inside sketch2 loop");
    delay (1000);
    func4 ();
  }

} // end of namespace sketch2

// MAIN LOOP AND SETUP

void setup()
{
  pinMode (10, INPUT_PULLUP);
  if (digitalRead (10) == HIGH)
  {
    sketch1::setup ();
    while (true)
      sketch1::loop ();
  }
  else
  {
    sketch2::setup ();
    while (true)
      sketch2::loop ();
  }
}   // end of setup

void loop()
{

} // end of loop
```

In my example I am testing a pin (10) to see if sketch1 or sketch2 should run.

---

> yet run them one after another

Yes, well sketches normally keep running inside `loop` forever, so you would need a way of deciding when to exit the sketch and run the other one. My example shows how you can choose between one or the other based on a digital input.

---

> I tried it but it is showing that the functions are not declared in this scope.

### Important note re function prototypes

It looks like the IDE's automatic generation of function prototypes doesn't work inside namespaces. Thus you need to do either:

- Make your own function prototypes (that is the function declaration without the actual function code) - see sketch 1 above; or
- Declare a function before it is used (sketch 2 above)

If this is someone else's code you may find it easier to just add the function prototypes as required. When you get the error message, find the function it is referring to, copy the "declaration" part, eg.

```
void foo (int a, int b)
```

Add a semicolon, eg.

```
void foo (int a, int b);
```

Then put that **before** it is called. Make sure it is still inside the namespace.

---

> can I call the setup if first namespace then some func. respective to that namespace then call the setup of second namespace and call func. from that namespace and keep all this in an infinite loop?

Well, you *can* do that, but you need to realize what each sketch is doing. For example if sketch1 turns some pins to output, but sketch2 assumes they are still inputs, then you need to undo that.

> And what is it to wrapup a function and 'how' to do it.

You need to inspect the sketches and see what they have done, so you can "undo" it. For example:

```
void wrapup ()
  {
  // set all pins to inputs and LOW
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
    pinMode (i, INPUT);
    digitalWrite (i, LOW);
    }
  // if Serial used
  Serial.flush ();  // flush output
  Seral.end ();    // stop serial hardware

  // and so on

  }   // end of wrapup
```

Comment: I tried it but it is showing that the functions are not declared in this scope. The program didn't compile 2nd Q: And will sketch1::loop (); will run the loop of sketch1 forever?. I want it to run once and next sketch should run. The 2 codes should run one after another indefinitely without any condition. how shall i achieve that?. Or can you please provide me your email so that i can send you the codes and you could combine them if you've got a bit of time. please it would be a great help as i am a newbie and will truly appreciate your work.

Comment: Nick's code compiles for me. The problem is with your changes. Try and fix them, and if you can't, create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post a new question.

Comment: Regarding making them one one after the other, I don't think there's a one-size-fits-all answer for that. Really you need to understand what the code is doing, and find a way to adjust it. That's the fun of Arduinos anyway.

Comment: As I said in my answer, most Arduino sketches are designed to loop forever. So to make one proceed after the other you have to redesign that paradigm. And no, I'm not giving you my email address.

Comment: See amended answer about generating function prototypes.

Comment: Thanks. that problem was solved by doing as you said. One problem still persists. one of the two codes that i mentioned also has custom libraries attached to it and has .h, .cpp files too. when compiling there are errors like undefined references. first code does not have any custom libraries.  so i removed the namespace from the second code(having custom libraries) and only called sketch1 in the second code like sketch1::setup ();. But this too gives only one error which is  undefined reference to `sketch1::SPIClass::begin()'

Comment: The `#include` statements need to be at global scope (not in a namespace). After all you need the library anyway and there won't be name clashes with the libraries (or hopefully not anyway). There is no point in hiding that inside a namespace. Also the automatic library detection that the IDE does probably won't work if you have the `#include` in a namespace.

Comment: Thank You @NickGammon The Cube now works fine and the program runs smoothly.

Comment: Just one more question i wanted to ask. At the main (final) setup and loop, can the functions which are inside the namespaces be called individually?.My Aim is to run one namespace sketch after another 'unconditionally'(the present condition is dependent upon the pin (switch) to be 1 or 0). i.e in the main loop can i call the setup if first namespace then some func. respective to that namespace then call the setup of second namespace and call func. from that namespace and keep all this in an infinite loop. Or is there any way you know to run these sketches one after another unconditionally.

Comment: Namespaces are just ways of organizing function (and variable) names. You can certainly call from one namespace to the other. For example inside namespace `sketch2` you could call `sketch1::setup ();`. Just be careful that any resources used in one sketch are released before you switch to the other one. You might make a function `wrapup` that releases resources (for example, setting any output pins back to input).

Comment: Yes, the same problem is occuring to me.I first call sketch1::setup (); then  call a function from sketch1 like sketch1::func1 ();. then i call setup of sketch 2 and then func if sketch 2 for eg.  sketch2::setup (); then sketch2::func6 ();. here what happens is , func1 runs properly but func6 does not run.And  Suppose i first call setup and  fun6 from sketch1, funcs in sketch2 dont run after them.(i.e the functions called first called sketch work and the functions from next called sketch dont run) .how to solve this problem. And what is it to wrapup a function and 'how' to do it.

Comment: See amended answer.

Comment: Re. your `wrapup()`: you don't need to `digitalWrite(i, LOW)` after `pinMode(i, INPUT)` (doesn't hurt either...), as `pinMode()` takes care of both the PORT and DDR registers when setting the pin as either `INPUT` or `INPUT_PULLUP`. Only when you set a pin to `OUTPUT` it leaves the PORT register in whatever state it was before.

Comment: @NickGammon In the past I did something similar, but I did it in this way: `void (*loop_ptr)();
/* in the setup */
if (..) { setup1(); loop_ptr = loop1; } else { setup2(); loop_ptr = loop2; }
/* in the loop */
void loop() { loop_ptr(); }`. This is because outside the loop there is some code in the arduino main. Another way would be to set a variable and inside the loop call `void loop() { if (use_prg1) loop1(); else loop2(); }`. What do you think? PS sorry for double comment, but I mistakenly pressed enter before and now I can't modify the previous one

Comment: That's OK if it works, but if you have other functions (say from example code) which happen to have the same name then you get name clashes. The namespace idea isolates each bunch of code into a non-clashing area.

Comment: @Nick, your answer is masterful.  As usual.  I always learn something new from your posts and I will keep this in mind.  But I think it might be a bit overwhelming for this user.

Comment: @SDsolar Thanks! It may or may not be too complex for some users, but it might give others an idea for how to fairly simply merge two sketches that have the same function or variable names. :)